# xPages DataView and Repeat control

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

I have two forms in a database: fmKopf (head) and fmPos (position). I have a DataView which I am using to show me all the fmKopf documents - this works perfectly. The var name for the records are "rowHandle". I have added a repeat control to the details section of the dataView where I would like to display the fmPos documents for the fmKopf. The repeat var name is "rowData". The value for the repleat control is:

```
var posView:NotesView = database.getView("xpPositions");
if (rowHandle.isDocument()) {
    var key = rowHandle.getColumnValue("searchKey"); 
    var vecLieferscheine:NotesViewEntryCollection = posView.getAllDocumentsByKey(key);
    return vecLieferscheine;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

I then added a computed field within the repeat control but for the life of me do not know what to use to display the corresponding data from the fmPos document. If I just display rowData I get the UID of the Notes documents - this makes sense as we are returning a NotesViewEntryCollection. I then tried the following code:

```
var doc:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(rowData);
return doc.getItemValue("DLNTLP");
```

to display the field DLNTLP from the fmPos document - this cannot work as rowData is a NotesViewEntryCollection and not a single value. This causes the page to crash.

What would be the code that I need to get the computed field to display the values from the underlying documents?

Thank you for any help given.
Ursus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i had to edit the answer multiple times dont know why but stackoverflow timed me out.

1. getAllDocumentsByKey(key) does not return a NotesViewEntryCollection it returns a NotesDocumentCollection wich does not really mather you just skip the .getDocument();
2. So in your `xp:repeat` you already have NotesDocuments, you can work with them you dont need to get the documents from your database using `database.getDocumentByUNID()`.

You can use following code to access your documents via a datasource inside your repeat (wich does more or less the same as database.getDocumentByUNID()):

```
<xp:repeat
    id="repeat1" rows="30"
    value="YourCode" var="detailDoc">
        <xp:panel 
           <xp:this.data>
                <xp:dominoDocument var="document1"
                    action="openDocument"
                    documentId="#{javascript:detailDoc.getUniversalID()}">
                </xp:dominoDocument>
        </xp:this.data>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:repeat>
```

or direkt access every Document from your Collection:

```
<xp:repeat
    id="repeat1" rows="30"
    value="YourCode" var="detailDoc">
        <xp:panel 
          <xp:text>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://
                     var  doc:NotesDocument = detailDoc;
                     return doc.getItemValueString('DLNTLP');
             </xp:this.value>
         </xp:text>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:repeat>
```

If you just need one or two fields from your documents i would use the secound methode, the first is very usefull if you also want to manipulate those fields because you can use the document datasource with all it's features. The first example also is usefull if you want to display attachments.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you for that - been looking all day for the answer :o) If you are near me sometime (Vorarlberg) let me buy you a beer please! Now, off to try and replicate a Embeded Single Category view in XPages - i.e. display the same position documents when I have opened the document in the frontend.